# Powershell, find many Locked User in file with select-string

Tags: powershell

I want find many User, who have locked account in my file.txt

file.txt:

```
Login:                  ID:
User_SameAccountName     1111111112
User_SameAccountName2    1234252566
User_SameAccountName3    13124251255
```

My powershell script:

```
$myarray = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | select SamAccountName

$i = 1
while($i -le 5){
Select-String -Pattern "$myarray[$i]" -Path E:\file.txt
$i += 1

}
```

I dont have any errors. Script run and looks everything is OK but dont have result

When I do this commands with

```
Get-LocalUser | select name
```

in file.txt are LocalUser name, evrything is fine.

I need connect locked User with ID, but in AD account dont have this value: ID number, so I want search User by Search-ADAccount and take their ID from the file.

**I solved the problem like this**

```
$myarray = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$result = foreach ($i in $myarray){
Select-String -Path "mypath" -pattern $i | select -ExpandProperty Line}
$result | out-file 'mypath2'
```

Comment: What is that `ID` property? `EmployeeId` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

- Populate `$array` with the **SamAccountName** for locked out accounts
- **NOTE:** Each **SamAccountName** is type cast into a `[string]`
- Use `Get-Content` to pull in data/lines from the text file **(1)** Iterate through each line, **(2)** split the line on `" "`, and **(3)** check if `$array` contains the index `[0]` from the split
- If it does, then print out the corresponding ID by splitting the line on again `" "` and selecting the last index in the result array

```
$array = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut |  ForEach-Object { "$($_.SamAccountName)" }
Get-Content -Path "path-to-txt-file" | ForEach-Object { if ($array.Contains($_.Split(" ")[0].Trim())) { Write-Host "Locked ID: $($_.Split(" ")[-1].Trim())" } }
```

Comment: Dont work. I need connect locked User with ID, but in AD account dont have this value: ID number, so I want search User by Search-ADAccount and take their ID from the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allLockedUsers = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly | %{ "$($_.SamAccountName)" }

$results = Get-Content -Path "file.txt" | %{
   $m = $_ -match '^User_([^\s]+)'
   if ($m -and $Matches[1] -in $allLockedUsers) { $_ }
}
```